forbidden (403) CSRF was not verified. The request was cancelled
I am logogin with super admin in django project and want to change some properties of users but when i clicked at save button it shows an error as below:
forbidden (403)
CSRF was not verified. The request was cancelled.
Help
Reason given for failure:
Origin checking failed - https://somedomain.com does not match any trusted origins.

In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django’s CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:
Your browser is accepting cookies.
The view function passes a request to the template’s render method.
In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
The form has a valid CSRF token. After logging in in another browser tab or hitting the back button after a login, you may need to reload the page with the form, because the token is rotated after a login.

You’re seeing the help section of this page because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and only the initial error message will be displayed.
You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.
I am new in stackoverflow and this is my first question please help me!

You will need to add this line to your settings.py
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://example.com']

And if you would like to include subdomains you can add this.
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://*.example.com']

this will allow for all subdomains to be included.

thanks a lot my dear but it does nt solved my problem may be its belongs to ssl certificate but I do nt how can I solve
